# Where to put logic shared by multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I'm working on an iPhone app (Objective-C) which has barcode scanning functionality on many of its screens. The user can tap a control to recognize different barcodes and navigate to different screens depending on what type of barcode is recognized. The majority of the logic does not depend on which screen they initiated the scan from... As such, I don't want to duplicate the code in each view controller, but am uncertain where the best place for it is. It requires the user tapping on a detection rectangle, so it does need to be able to handle these events. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any problem with the controllers that need this ability all deriving from the same parent class?  Alternatively, can you implement it as a category of UIViewController?

Comment: As Phillip said, category is a good idea.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the suggestions!! @PhillipMills not afaik, but what might be some things to look out for? Does a category make more sense sense I'm mainly trying to add additional functionality?

Comment: The only problem with a category (and the reason I made it the second suggestion) is that it applies to **all** objects of the type, which might be broader than you want.  Creating a parent class restricts the effect to its children.  That makes more sense if the controllers you're talking about all derive from the same parent currently.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!! How might I "accept" this given it is a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a singleton

```
class DataStore {
    static let sharedDataStore = DataStore()

    func scanBarcode() {
        //logic
    }
}
```

calling the function in another View Controller

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

    let shared = DataStore.sharedDataStore

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //calling the function
        shared.scanBarcode()
    }
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use a singleton. Singletons should be reserved for when there can only be one. eg UIDevice. Best